# Mac disk is full but I can't figure out why

Tags: macos, disk-space

I have a 500GB SSD on my macbook running Yosemite.

Recently, I have been getting a lot of out-of-disk space message. I have been deleting and deleting. According to every disk usage application I have tried (including Disk Expert, Disk Wave, Omni Disk Sweeper) I am using about 130GB.

- 32 GB Applications
- 10 GB Library
- 8 GB System
- 80 GB Users

Yet the Mac says only 13GB out of 512GB are free. So there is a huge discrepancy. I have cleaned log files and caches. I have run disk check which has reported no errors. I have rebooted (naturally). None of the tools above showed the missing data.

Moving to the command line, I find what looks like the symptom of the problem:

```
$ sudo du -cxhd 1 /
338G    /.DocumentRevisions-V100
```

My guess then is that the versioning feature has run amok. How can I address this discrepancy between the used disk space and the free disk space?

Comment: You should run the disk usage applications as root, if that's why they're not telling you about a 338G folder just sitting in `/`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply delete that folder, since it contains older versions of your documents, not the current ones.

*If the information on your SSD is of value to you, it would be wise to ensure you have a backup of it before proceeding any further.*

To delete the DocumentRevisions folder you can triple click on the line below to select it:-

```
/.DocumentRevisions-V100
```

Then right click the highlighted line, select `Services->Reveal in Finder`.
The DocumentsRevisions folder should then appear in a Finder window, move it to Trash, empty trash, and restart your Mac.

Alternatively you could delete it via terminal if you prefer, but then you need to use sudo (or su) for the rm command.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a disk that you replaced after you bought your computer, you may need to verify your *trim* settings. 
Please [check this 2015 document](https://randomnerds.com/execute-sudo-trimforce-enable-to-keep-your-ssd-healthy/) on setting trim.